# BotFramework webchat Curl taking too long (> 2 seconds)

Tags: botframework

We have several azure bots in production

We use REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-overview

We are experiencing long CURL times (Above 2 seconds) for every activity (even simple ones)

this is curl info sample result

```
[url] => https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/conversations/XXXXXXXXXX/activities
[content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 391
[request_size] => 1422
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 2.90444
[namelookup_time] => 0.25305
[connect_time] => 0.333904
[pretransfer_time] => 0.507724
[size_upload] => 148
[size_download] => 170
[speed_download] => 58
[speed_upload] => 50
[download_content_length] => 170
[upload_content_length] => 148
[starttransfer_time] => 2.904391
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )
```

these are CURL parameters

```
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 2,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,  
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
            "content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"),
        ));
```

1 - Does the time depends on the client speed ?
2 - Is there any curl parameter affecting the performance ?

Answer (score 2):

> experiencing long CURL times (Above 2 seconds) for every activity (even simple ones)

To troubleshoot the issue, you can try to turn on [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) with your bot application that you host on Azure web app and specify it as messaging endpoint, which could help us trace the **Server response time** of request.

[image]

If the **Server response time** is long, please check if other apps in the same App Service plan are consuming compute resources. If possible, you can try to specify a new App Service plan for your bot application independently from the other apps the existing plan, and check if it can help improve performance.

If the **Server response time** is normal (not long), as you suspected, other factors, such as network etc, might cause the issue.